# MySQL Unknown column in having clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get all the wins per team, however, SQL decides to throw an error

[image]

The following query is being executed:

```
SELECT `t`.`teamcode`, COUNT(*) AS `gewonnen`
FROM `Team` `t`
INNER JOIN `Wedstrijd` `w` ON `w`.`teamthuis` = `t`.`teamcode`
GROUP BY `w`.`teamthuis`
HAVING `w`.`scorethuis` > `w`.`scoreuit`

#1054 - Unknown column 'w.scorethuis' in 'having clause'
```

Without aliases:

```
SELECT `Team`.`teamcode`, COUNT(*) AS `gewonnen`
FROM `Team`
INNER JOIN `Wedstrijd` ON `Wedstrijd`.`teamthuis` = `Team`.`teamcode`
GROUP BY `Wedstrijd`.`teamthuis`
HAVING `Wedstrijd`.`scorethuis` > `Wedstrijd`.`scoreuit`

#1054 - Unknown column 'Wedstrijd.scorethuis' in 'having clause'
```

Comment: Are you sure that `Wedstrijd` has a column with the name `scorethuis`?

Comment: @MahmoudGamal Well pretty sure, check the image ;)

Comment: @user2196728 It's not the aliases, tried it without

Comment: Apart from the fact that the `having` clause does not do what you think it does, is the column `scorethuis` or `scorehuis`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff it is scorethuis yes

I tried removing the column and putting another column in the having clause and it doesn't recognize any of them so it's not the column

Comment: Do not understand the downvote here. I'm stumped by this error too. Was really curious on the reason behind it.

Comment: @DBC I still find it hard to see the actual issue here xD I think it's because I'm using count, it will force it to return only one row so saying group by, will have no effect(I quess)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no need to use `HAVING`. Try `WHERE` instead:

```
SELECT `t`.`teamcode`, COUNT(*) AS `gewonnen`
FROM `Team` `t`
INNER JOIN `Wedstrijd` `w` ON `w`.`teamthuis` = `t`.`teamcode`
WHERE `w`.`scorethuis` > `w`.`scoreuit`
GROUP BY `w`.`teamthuis`
```

Comment: Yep that's it, thanks, could you explain why having doesn't work in this case?

Comment: @Mazzy I think this is because the column `scorethuis` is not included in the `GROUP BY`, the error is misleading actually :)

Comment: I believe it is because I'm performing scorethuis > scoreuit on EVERY row and not on the actual group :)

Comment: This solution only worked for me, but only when I had the WHERE clause *before* the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you had select `w`.`scorethuis`  `w`.`scoreuit` both in select statement then 'Having;' would work.  But I faced the same problem and I resolved it by the above way.

```
SELECT `t`.`teamcode`, COUNT(*),***`w`.`scorethuis`, `w`.`scoreuit`*** AS `gewonnen`
FROM `Team` `t`
INNER JOIN `Wedstrijd` `w` ON `w`.`teamthuis` = `t`.`teamcode`
GROUP BY `w`.`teamthuis`
HAVING `w`.`scorethuis` > `w`.`scoreuit`
```